# Operator Overloading in C++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have doubt whether we can do the following or not.

Suppose I have created two instance of class `A` i.e. `obj1` and `obj2` and class `A` has member function `show()`.

Can I use the following?

```
(obj1+obj2).show()
```

If yes, how? If no, why it is not possible?

Comment: What behavior would you expect from that code?

Comment: Are you asking whether you can invoke a member function on the result of a previous operation (possibly not realising that `op+` there is a function call)?

Comment: I just want to display the  total value(i.e. obj1.x+obj2.x) using show method without changing the value of both the instance using above technique...

Comment: I knw we can perform the same using 
obj3 = obj1+obj2;
obj3.show();
But if we can do directly why should we use another instance.... That was my basic point of view.....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes it is possible, just implement operator+ for A and have it return a class of type A:

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:
    explicit A(int v) : value(v) {}

    void show() const { std::cout << value << '\n'; }

    int value;
};

A operator+(const A& lhs, const A& rhs)
{
    A result( lhs.value + rhs.value );
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    A a(1);
    A b(1);

    (a+b).show(); // prints 2!

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it if you overload the `+` operator in such a way that it takes two arguments of type `A` and yields an object that has a method named `show`.

Answer (score 2):

If obj1+obj2 does return an object that have a  show() function member, then yes it's possible.

If not, it is not.

So, it depends on the operator+ function that is used here, that depends on both types of obj1 and obj2.

obj1+obj2 is an expression that have a type, the type of the object returned by the operation, like any expression. Now, once the expression is executed, you have this object. But as here you don't associate it to a name (using assignation for example), it is a "temporary", meaning it will be destroyed at the end of the full expression.

So, if the resulting temporary object's type does provide a show() function then you can call it like you did.

If it don't provide a show() function, then you're trying to call a function that don't exists.

So in any case, the compiler will stop you, it will not be a runtime error.

I would be you, I would setup a minimal test project just to play with those principles.

Comment: Why does it need to be `const`? A temporary is **not** `const`. [Look at this](http://www.ideone.com/u4Z1t). Perhaps you're getting confused because you cannot bind temporaries to `refs-to-non-const` (which is a completely different issue).

Comment: "if [+] return an object [having] constant show()" - this limitation is only true if `operator+` returns a `const` object, which is often sensible (in line with C++ generally not allowing temporaries to be lvalues) but optional.

Comment: Interesting, AFAIK it shouldn't... Or maybe it's because of optimizations (inlining)? As specified by the +operator, the returning object is a temporary, so it shouldn't be modifiable. show isn't const so it should not be callable there...

Comment: @Klaim: Can you provide some evidence for your assertion that temporaries cannot be modified? That seems like nonsense to me.

Comment: @Tony: temporaries are implicitely const...right? It depends on how the operator is called and here there is no assignation so it's really a temporary.....am I right?

Comment: Sorry I'm wrong, there is a nuance : temporaries can only be referenced with const references, but that don't make them const. I'll modify the answer.

Comment: @Klaim: Sorry, but no - not for objects, where the programmer's "God" and gets to decide, having `operator+` return a `const` object or not. Nothing to do with inlining either.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I mixed with reference assignation and life extension rules :)

Comment: @Klaim: Apologies, seems you're right. They _are_ non-modifiable in C++03. Come join us in the C++ chat room where we're discussing it.

Comment: Wait what? XD Ok I'm joining but IO'm not sure the company proxy will allow it...

Comment: @Klaim: Sorry again, but [you _are_ wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6466253/if-temporaries-are-implicitly-const-how-does-this-work/6466316#6466316). The call to member function `show` should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can use it if you have overloaded the `+` operator of `class A` to return an obect of `class A`.

Answer (score 1):

Write an operator overload for + operator and define the operation you want on that.

In the operator overload for + operator just update the logic you want like adding the individual member variables or concatenating the names etc meaningfully based on your use case

Then you can call That new object.Show() function just like an object calling member function.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what the result type of `obj1+obj2` is and whether `.show()` is a constant method.

Comment: [`show()` doesn't need to be `const`.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6466253/if-temporaries-are-implicitly-const-how-does-this-work/6466316#6466316)

Answer (score -2):

No! The result of (obj1+obj2) isn't object. You may overload "="
and use:

```
obj3 = obj1 + obj2;
obj3.show();
```

Comment: Why not? If you can write `obj3 = obj1 + obj2` then do stuff with `obj3`, then you may absolutely write `(obj1 + obj2).show()`.