# How can you modify an object without calling member functions?

Tags: c++

At 3.10/10, the standard says:

> An lvalue for an object is necessary in order to modify the object except that an rvalue of class type can also be used to modify its referent under certain circumstances. [Example: a member function called for an object (9.3) can modify the object. ]

So, rvalues are non-modifiable except under certain circumstances. We're told that calling a member function is one of those exceptions. This gives the idea that there are ways of modifying objects other than calling a member function. I can't think of a way.

How can one modify an object without calling a member function?

Comment: Would writing a field of the object be considered modifying it?

Comment: (This came out of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6466253/if-temporaries-are-implicitly-non-modifiable-how-does-this-work.)

Comment: With great difficulty. For one, you can't use functions since you can't get a mutable ref through the call.

Comment: @Martinho: Did you mean "This gives the idea that you **can't** modify an object without calling a member function"

Comment: @Sasha, well yes, of course that would be modification. (How could I forget that?)

Answer (score 3):

> How can one modify an object [that's specified by an rvalue expression] without calling a member function?

I know of only one way to do that, namely to bind the object to a reference to `const`, and then cast away the `const`-ness.

E.g.

```
template< class Type >
Type& tempRef( Type const& o ) { return const_cast< Type& >( o ); }

struct S { int x; };

int main()
{ tempRef( S() ).x = 3; }
```

This is because a temporary object is not `const` itself unless it is of `const` type, so the example above does not cast away original `const`-ness (which would be UB).

**EDIT**, added: [Luc Danton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6466624/how-can-you-modify-an-object-without-calling-member-functions/6467332#6467332)’s answer showed another (non-general) way, namely where the temporary's construction stores some reference or pointer to the object in some accessible location.

Cheers & hth.,

Comment: "This is because a temporary object is not const itself unless it is of const type", that's only guaranteed to be the case in C++0x though - should be mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

This [seems to be accepted](http://www.ideone.com/Cqmzj):

```
struct T {
   int x;
};

int main() {
   T().x = 3;
}
```

I am slightly surprised that this works, because IIRC the LHS of `op=` must be an lvalue, yet the following implies that [even `T().x` is an rvalue](http://www.ideone.com/3QV0R):

```
struct T {
   int x;
};

void f(int& x) {
   x = 3;
}

int main() {
   f(T().x);
}
```

**Edit:** As of 4.6, GCC *does* warn about `T().x = 3`: `error: using temporary as lvalue`.

I can't think of any other way to modify a class object other than through data member access or member function calls. So, I'm going to say... **you can't**.

Comment: g++ says `error: using temporary as lvalue [-fpermissive]` on the line `T().x = 3;`.

Comment: @Fred: what flags are you using? `g++ -Wall -Wextra -pedantic` gives me no output on the first example.

Comment: It is additionally possible to modify objects of appropriate types through e.g. `std::memset` but since this needs a pointer it cannot be applied to rvalues either.

Comment: @Martinho: None, I just say `g++ foobar.cpp`. I use g++ 4.6.0

Comment: @Fred: confirmed. 4.6 does indeed warn. For the record 4.5 doesn't.

Comment: @Thomalak: it's no big mystery. The first example invokes the automatically generated copy assignment operator, which is a member function. The second example doesn't. But you are on to a decidedly silly effect of the rules, namely that you can assign to the complete class type rvalue result of a function call (this uses the assignment operator), but not to individual fundamental type parts of it. Heh. :-)

Comment: @Alf: That famous copy assignment operator for `int`.

Comment: @Thomalak: oh, sorry, I didn't see that (since you wrote that it seems to be accepted). That's a buggy compiler. Try it with [Comeau Online](http://www.comeaucomputing.com/tryitout/), it will give you correct error message.

Comment: GCC 4.6 has rvalue references, so it doesn't conform to C++03 but C++0x which has different rules. However, it's worth noticing that the fact that you can only bind rvalues to const lvalue references is irrelevant of their constness.

Comment: @DeadMG: Not by default. You need --std=c++0x for that.

Comment: @Fred, @Martinho: does gcc 4.6 (no access to it yet) warn if `x` is a custom class instead of a plain `int` ?

Comment: @Matthieu: btw my comment above said "warn" but it was a mistake on my part. It's an *error*. interesting: given `struct U{int y;}; struct T{U x;};` I get the following: `T().x = U()` produces no diagnostic, while `T().x.y = 3` produces the error.

Comment: @Martinho: I ought to have said "diagnose" rather than "warn" (the snippet clearly says "error" anyway) but it doesn't matter hugely.

Comment: @Martinho: It makes sense: `T().x = U()` uses compiler-generated `operator=(const U&)`, which _is_ member function.

Comment: @Vitus: Ah! dumb me, I didn't realized :/

Comment: `T().x` is an *rvalue* of *non-class* type. It is not legal to say `T().x = ...;`. It's also not an example of modifying an *rvalue* of *class* type :)

Answer (score 1):

Modifying a temporary and not through an lvalue to that temporary:

```
#include <cstring>

class standard_layout {
    standard_layout();
    int stuff;
};

standard_layout* global;

standard_layout::standard_layout()
{ global = this; }

void
modify(int)
{
    std::memset(global, 0, sizeof *global);
}

int
main()
{
    modify( (standard_layout {}, 0) );
}
```

I don't think it's correct to assume that rvalues of class types are non-modifiable. I now understand that paragraph as 'for non-class types, an lvalue for an object is needed in order to modify that object'.

Comment: Yet that's what the standard says in 3.10/10. Aren't you using an lvalue here? Or is it pertinent that the object was _originally_ seen as an rvalue? Argh!

Comment: @Tomalak `global` as it appears in the call to memset is an lvalue, but not an lvalue *for the object* being modified (that would be `*global`), as appears in the paragraph.

Comment: @Luc: Hmm ok. Presumably, though, at some point `memset` is using `*global`.

Comment: @Tomalak I believe a `memset` that uses char pointers would be conforming (and, well, plain obvious) and `*(char*)this` is not an lvalue for `*this`.

Comment: @Luc: No lvalue-to-rvalue conversion for "use"?

Comment: @Luc: Ah, for the pointer copy but not for the actual eventual pointee modification. OK, nice! I'm glad that this means I don't have to change [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6466253/if-temporaries-are-implicitly-non-modifiable-how-does-this-work/6466316#6466316) where I stole your code.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of one way:

If your class exposes public member variables, you can assign directly to those member variables.  For example:

```
class A
{
    public:
        int _my_var;
...
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    A *a = new C();
    a->_my_var = 10;
}
```

This is not a good programming style though - exposing a member variable as public isn't something I would advocate or even suggest.

Also, if you can do something really weird, such as directly writing some address in memory, an offset from the pointer to the class object - but why would you do that?

Comment: I would put this as a comment if I could

Comment: "Also, if you can do something really weird, such as directly writing some address in memory, an offset from the pointer to the class object" How? The temporary ceases to exist before you get a chance, and it has no memory address.

Comment: What does this answer have to do with rvalues?

Answer (score 0):

> How can one modify an object without calling a member function?

By assigning a value to one of the object's visible data members, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Doing an implicit cast is sort of like calling a member function -- also modifying rvalue refs seems to work.

Tested the following in vc++10 and g++ 4.4.

```
struct b { int i; b(int x) : i(x) {} };
struct a { int i; a() : i(0) { } operator b() { return i++ /* this works */, b(i); } };
a f(a&& x) { return x.i++ /* this works */, x; }
int main() { b b = f(a()); /* implicit operator b() cast; b.i will equal 2 */ }
```

Answer (score -1):

A member function can change the member directly, but it can also delegate that responsibility:

```
struct Foo {
  int x;
  void Bar() { scanf("%d", &x); }
};
```

The current wording of the standard has the advantage that one doesn't need to argue whether this is a case of `Bar` changing the object. If we'd agree that `scanf` changes the object, then that's just another example.

Comment: Huh, you're *calling a member function*. And we don't need to argue whether this is a case of `Bar` changing the object **because it does**, not because of any wording in the standard. You're taking a *non-const pointer* to a member.