# Significance of parentheses in decltype((c))?

Tags: c++, c++11, decltype

I was reading [this article on Wikipedia regarding `C++11` *Type Inference* feature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11#Type_inference).

There is an example and I quote:

```
#include <vector>
int main() {  
    const std::vector<int> v(1);  
    auto a = v[0];        // a has type int  
    decltype(v[1]) b = 1; // b has type const int&, the return type of  
                          //   std::vector<int>::operator[](size_type) const  
    auto c = 0;           // c has type int  
    auto d = c;           // d has type int  
    decltype(c) e;        // e has type int, the type of the entity named by c  
    decltype((c)) f = c;  // f has type int&, because (c) is an lvalue  
    decltype(0) g;        // g has type int, because 0 is an rvalue  
}
```

in the following lines:

```
    decltype(c) e;        // e has type int, the type of the entity named by c  
    decltype((c)) f = c;  // f has type int&, because (c) is an lvalue
```

What's the difference between `c` and `(c)`?  Why does `(c)` represent an *lvalue*?

Comment: That's not an operator...

Comment: if that changes `int` to `int&` that's an operator.

Comment: @MBZ: That doesn't make it an "operator" whatsoever.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

- `c` is the name of a variable;
- `(c)` is an expression, in this case an *lvalue* expression, whose value is identical to the value of the variable `c`.

And the two are treated differently by `decltype`. Consider, for example, `decltype(1+2)`, which is also an example taking an *expression*. It just so happens that your example is a *simple* version of an expression: one which merely names a single variable and does nothing exciting with it.

It's one of those differences that you generally only really care about if you're rationalising about the subtle parts of the language specification; though, as you have identified, it has quite a significant practical effect in this case.

Please note though that there is no *operator* usage here. It's all simply a deduction from the layout of the grammar.

Comment: Can you explain why decltype(1+2) shouldn't be `const int` for example?

Comment: @user814628 why would it be? Addition doesn't make it `const`.

Comment: I guess for me it feels more natural for (1+2) to be constant because its a temporary result.

Comment: [Temporaries are not inherently constant](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6466253/if-temporaries-are-implicitly-non-modifiable-how-does-this-work). However, you cannot mutate a literal and I think actually that `decltype(1+2)` is `int`; I worry therefore that I may have made an error in judgment in stepping into this area of C++11 for this answer, as I'm no `decltype` expert.

Comment: see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2169932/non-class-rvalues-always-have-cv-unqualified-types

Comment: Isn't it `c` also an expression?

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès Yes. `decltype` simply has a special case: `decltype(expr)` gives the type and value category of the expression `expr` *except* if the expression is an unparenthesized identifier (+ some other exceptions), in which case it does something different (gives the `decl`ared `type` of the variable instead of the type and category the expression would have in any other context).

Answer (score 13):

I found a good description [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decltype#Semantics). It describes the difference between:

```
struct A { double x; };
const A* a = new A();
...
decltype(a->x) x4; // type is double
decltype((a->x)) x5; // type is const double&
```

and I quote:

> The reason for the difference between the latter two invocations of decltype is that the parenthesized expression `(a->x)` is neither an id-expression nor a member access expression, and therefore does not denote a named object. [[13](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2009/n2938.html)]
>
> Because the expression is an lvalue, its deduced type is "reference to the type of the expression", or `const double&`. [[10](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2343.pdf)]

Comment: It also contains the edits I made some time ago.. regarding the function call special cases. These edits need to be applied to your quoted article too by someone (I don't currently want to).

Comment: Instead of `decltype((e))`, why couldn't you just do `decltype(e)&`?