# Why and how do extra parentheses change the type of an expression in C++ (C++11)?

Tags: c++, c++11, parentheses, typeinfo

Under what circumstances do extra grouping parentheses break things in C++ (C++11 specifically)?  For reasons that are not relevant here, I ended up at one point with an expression that had an extra, unnecessary set of parens around it, and I discovered that the C++11 typeinfo function `is_same` was determining it to be a different type than the same code without the parentheses.  Here is a boiled-down example of the somewhat baffling behaviour:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  string s = "foo";
  cout << std::is_same<decltype(s), decltype(string("foo"))>::value;
  cout << std::is_same<decltype(s), decltype((s))>::value;
  cout << std::is_same<decltype((s)), decltype(string("foo"))>::value;
  cout << std::is_same<decltype((s)+"x"), decltype(string("foo")+"x")>::value;

  return 0;
}
```

This code prints "1001", which seems to indicate that the extra parens in the middle two lines cause the expression to be of a different type, but using that parenthesised expression in a larger expression makes it once again the same type.  On the other hand, if I use typeid to get a name for the type, `typeid(s)` and `typeid((s))` seem to produce the same thing.

I've now worked around the immediate problem, but I still don't understand why this happens in the first place; searching around for "double parentheses c++" and the like doesn't seem to turn up anything relevant (mostly pages about operator overloading, and compiler extensions that only activate after a specific keyword).

So: what the heck is going on here?  Why is the type of `s` different from the type of `(s)`?

Comment: There's a special rule for `decltype` that applies if the expression inside the `decltype`-parens is an *id-expression* or a *class-member-access*. Adding a second pair of parens makes it a *primary-expression* (but not itself an *id-expression* or *class-member-access*), so the special rule doesn't apply. See, e.g., http://stackoverflow.com/q/14115744/420683 or http://stackoverflow.com/q/3097779/420683

Comment: Also, `foo((1, 2));` has a different meaning than `foo(1, 2);`. Is this question generally about parentheses or about `decltype`?

Comment: Parentheses can also make a difference when applying a unary `&`: `struct foo { int m; void bar() { auto x = &foo::bar; auto y = &(foo::bar); } };` Here, `x` is of the type `int (foo::*)`, whereas `y` is of the type `int*`. But that's not specific to C++11.

Comment: @dyp About that last one: I think you mean `foo::m` rather than `foo::bar`.

Comment: @hvd Oops, of course. Too late for fixing it :( [Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a933035b24dc85dd) (with fix).

Comment: It seems @dyp's reference to http://stackoverflow.com/q/3097779/420683 has the answer. See e.g. https://ideone.com/FqrcEy, so that `decltype(s)` gives `string` and `decltype((s))` becomes `string &`.

Comment: @dyp could you explain your `foo(1,2)` example? Or did you mean the ADL-disabling `(foo)(1,2)`?

Comment: @TemplateRex `foo((1,2))` is a function call with only *one* argument expression, namely `(1,2)` is a single argument of value `2`. And disabling ADL is another nice example where parens matter :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`decltype` treats its arguments differently depending on the additional parentheses.

The second pair of parentheses makes it a primary-expression (but not itself an id-expression or class-member-access), so the special rule doesn't apply.

Here is a discussion: [Significance of parentheses in decltype((c))?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14115744/1065190)