# Why can I override the operators for - (negation) and ! (not) but not ~ (bitwise not)?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, gcc4.8

Why does the following define the `!` and `-` operators, but fail to define the `~` operator?

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <cstdint>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <cstdio>

template <typename T, T v>
struct integral_constant
    : std::integral_constant<T, v>
{
};

#define DECL_UNARY_OP(op) \
    template <typename T, T t> \
    constexpr integral_constant<decltype(op t), (op t)> \
    operator op(integral_constant<T, t>) \
    { return {}; } \


DECL_UNARY_OP(~);
DECL_UNARY_OP(-);
DECL_UNARY_OP(!);

int main() {
    constexpr auto x = integral_constant<uint8_t, 1>{};
    constexpr auto y = integral_constant<uint8_t, 10>{};
    constexpr auto z = integral_constant<uint8_t, 100>{};
    puts(typeid(-x).name());  // integral_constant<...>
    puts(typeid(~y).name());  // int!
    puts(typeid(!z).name());  // integral_constant<...>
}
```

Compiling this on GCC-4.8.2 gives [the following on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/g/X5B3Xo), where you can clearly see that the middle operation has decayed away from an `integral_constant` type.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Why do you ask ?

Comment: Upping the compiler version to gcc 6.1+ fixes it. It looks like you've either stumbled across UB or a now-patched compiler bug

Comment: My guess: this is a compiler bug with `~` which prefers the implicit conversion to a `uint8_t` then builtin `operator~`, rather than the function call to the newly defined `operator~`

Comment: All versions of Clang seem to do the right thing and not convert the result either. It seems like a bug indeed. On another note, I hope you are aware that your macro produces operators that promote integer types to `int`.

Comment: @Sid: Because I want it to not happen, and I'm stuck with that compiler version!

Comment: @StoryTeller: Yep, I'm aware that the result would end up `std::integral_constant<int, ...>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simpler reproduction can be obtained by eliminating `std::integral_constant`:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <cstdio>

template <typename T, T v>
struct integral_constant { };

template <typename T, T t>
constexpr integral_constant<decltype(~t), (~t)>
operator ~(integral_constant<T, t>) { return {}; }


int main() {
    constexpr auto y = integral_constant<uint8_t, 10>{};
    puts(typeid(~y).name());
}
```

Which now [fails to compile with](https://godbolt.org/g/RJhcSJ):

```
<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:17:17: error: no match for 'operator~' (operand type is 'const integral_constant<unsigned char, 10u>')
     puts(typeid(~y).name());
                 ^
<source>:17:17: note: candidate is:
<source>:11:1: note: template<class T, T t> constexpr integral_constant<decltype (~ t), (~ t)> operator~(integral_constant<T, t>)
 operator ~(integral_constant<T, t>)
 ^
<source>:11:1: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
<source>: In substitution of 'template<class T, T t> constexpr integral_constant<decltype (~ t), (~ t)> operator~(integral_constant<T, t>) [with T = unsigned char; T t = 10u]':
<source>:17:18:   required from here
<source>:11:1: error: 't' was not declared in this scope
Compiler returned: 1
```

It seems this can be fixed by adding extra parentheses,

```diff
-integral_constant<decltype(~t), (~t)>
+integral_constant<decltype((~t)), (~t)>
```

Comment: Extra parentheses? GCC is weird sometimes.

Comment: @StoryTeller: Perhaps it's parsing it as a destructor somehow?

Comment: IDK. It shouldn't matter really. A parenthesized expression has the exact same type and value category as the un-parenthesized one. I'm glad there's a workaround. But GCC is doing something weird.

Comment: @StoryTeller: [That's not true in general](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14130664/102441) - extra parentheses can change the type.

Comment: On the contrary. The lack of parentheses means the special rule is applied for a direct id expression / member. When you add parentheses, it becomes another expression, so the general rules for expressions kick in. But yeah, the rules for decltype are messed up.

Comment: You got me on a technicality there, I missed that your original comment said "expression" :)