# 2 questions about cppreference.com's explanation of decltype

Tags: c++, decltype, temporary

When I was reading [this online c++ reference page about decltype](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype)

I was wondering about this paragraph:

> If expression is a function call which returns a prvalue of class
> type or is a comma expression whose right operand is such a function call, **a temporary object is not introduced for that prvalue.**
> (until C++17)

**My question is: Introducing or not introducing a temporary, does that matter?**

And this paragraph:

> Note that if the name of an object is parenthesized, it is treated
> as an ordinary lvalue expression, thus **decltype(x) and decltype((x))** are often different types.

**And again my question: What's the rationale behind treating them differently?**

Can anyone out there give me a hand and shed some light on the dark corners I'm in. Thanks.

Comment: fyi the C++ Standard's papers for `decltype` - http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2343.pdf and http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3276.pdf

Comment: Perhaps it'd be good to add the [tag:language-lawyer] tag to attract language-lawyers.

Comment: [C++ decltype and parentheses - why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60375448/c-decltype-and-parentheses-why)

Comment: @RichardCritten Wow, a lot to stomach, but a quick scan shows that the paper details the origin of the issues and why the necessary wording adjustment was made. merci.

Comment: @cpplearner This seems to resolve the second part, really informative. Many thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Introducing or not introducing a temporary, does that matter?

This makes a bit more sense if you look at an expression that uses the result of a function:

```
// given
template<typename T> struct Foo {};
template<typename T> Foo<T> foo();
template<typename T> void bar(const Foo<T>&);

// This:
bar(foo<int>());

// Is equivalent to: 
{
  Foo<int>&& tmp = foo<int>();
  bar(tmp);
}

// So should tmp "exist" here?
using T = decltype(foo<int>());
```

You could easily argue that the `foo<int>()` expression actually is *equivalent* to `Foo<int>&& tmp = foo<int>()`. If the existence of `tmp` was somehow undesirable in a `decltype()` context, then it needs to be made clear.

And `tmp` is definitely undesirable here. It causes the `Foo<int>` specialization to be created. But just because you have identified a type does not mean you are actually using it. The same goes for type aliases.

Demonstration: (see on [godbolt](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/onKossdnh))

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
struct Foo {
    // Will cause a compile error if it's ever instantiated with int
    static_assert(!std::is_same_v<T, int>);
};

using FooInt = Foo<int>;

template<typename T>
Foo<T> foo() {
    return {};
}

void bar() {
  // Does not cause Foo<int> to exist just yet
  using T = decltype(foo<int>());

  // This instantiates Foo<int> and causes the compile error
  // T x;
}
```

> What's the rationale behind treating them differently?

**N.B.** This following is more of a guideline for how to reason about this. The actual technical details are different, but it can get rather convoluted.

Don't think of it as the parentheses being anything special. Instead, think of it as `decltype(id-expression)` being the special case.

Let's say we have the following declaration: `int x;`

The `x` expression does not behave like an `int`, but a `int&` instead. Otherwise `x = 3;` wouldn't make sense.

Despite that, `decltype(x)` is still `int`. That's the special case: `decltype(id-expression)` returns the type of the identifier itself instead of the type of the expression.

On the other hand, `(x)` also behaves like `int&`, but since it's not an `id-expression`, it gets interpreted as just any regular expression. So `decltype((x))` is `int&`.

```
#include <type_traits>

int x = 0;

using T = decltype(x);
using U = decltype((x));

static_assert(std::is_same_v<T, int>);
static_assert(std::is_same_v<U, int&>);
```

Comment: It's sometimes helpful to informally think of it as "the type of the `x` expression is `int&`", but that could lead to issues understanding other technical details. Technically an expression never has reference type. To be more precise, every expression has a type and a value category, and the ordinary `decltype` combines in the value category to sometimes get reference types. `(x)` is an lvalue of type `int`, so `decltype((x))` is `int&`. The `decltype(id-expression)` special case uses the type of the matching declarator instead of the type and category of the expression.

Comment: @aschepler Thank you. I've refined the wording a bit to avoid misleading people, but kept the simplified perspective to keep the answer as beginner-friendly as possible.

Comment: Really informative and helpful. Thanks.