# Why is decltype deducing rvalue reference for a named value?

Tags: c++, move-semantics, decltype

In the following example:

```
#include <iostream>
 
class A {};

void TestValueCategory(A& ft_) {
    (void)ft_;
    std::cout << "   TestValueCategory(&)...\n";
}   
    
void TestValueCategory(const A& ft_) {
    (void)ft_;
    std::cout << "   TestValueCategory(const &)...\n";
}
    
void TestValueCategory(A&& ft_) {
    (void)ft_;
    std::cout << "   TestValueCategory(&&)...\n"; 
}

template<typename U>
void Forwarder(U&& u_) {
    TestValueCategory(std::forward<U>(u_));
}   
    
auto funcRVOauto() {
    return A();
}
 

int main()
{
    auto&& rv = funcRVOauto();
    std::cout << "\nrv addr [" << (void*)&rv << "]\n";
    std::cout << "rv Value-category is" << (std::is_rvalue_reference<decltype(rv)>::value == true ? "" : " NOT") << " rvalue ref\n";
    Forwarder(rv); //Forwarder(std::move(rv) prints TestValueCategory(&&), as expected
}
```

Output:

```
rv addr [0x7fff9434cc6f]
rv Value-category is rvalue ref
   TestValueCategory(&)...
```

How is decltype able to deduce that the 'original' value category of rv is rvalue reference?
Within the context of main, it is a named value after all (e.g. I can take its address), not an x value.

As a follow up, on further reseaerch I found out this same issue has been discussed here:

[C++ decltype and parentheses - why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60375448/c-decltype-and-parentheses-why)

[What is decltype and how is it used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18815221/what-is-decltype-and-how-is-it-used)

Comment: `decltype` deduces type, not value category

Comment: @user7860670 When applied to an expression, it deduces both. http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type.decltype#1.4 OP doesn't apply it to an expression though.

Comment: `decltype(...)` has custom behavior for unparenthesized variable names, for them it returns the type as specified in the variable declaration. `decltype((rv))` would give you an lvalue reference as you expect.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Thank you; I see now my question is a subset of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18815221/what-is-decltype-and-how-is-it-used