# Default template argument deducing to the wrong type in a conditional

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I have the following testcase:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename Ty_>
using conditional_ref = 
    typename std::conditional<std::is_fundamental<Ty_>::value, Ty_, Ty_ const&>::type;

template <typename Ty_, typename Ty2_ = conditional_ref<Ty_>>
inline void f(Ty2_ arg1) {
  static_assert(std::is_same<Ty2_, conditional_ref<Ty_>>::value, "uh-oh!");
}

int main() {
  struct A {};
  A a{};
  double b{};

  //f(a);                                           // Cannot deduce parameter (expected)
  //f(b);                                           // Cannot deduce parameter (expected)
  f<decltype(a)>(a);                                // uh-oh!
  f<decltype(b)>(b);                                // OK
  f<decltype(a), conditional_ref<decltype(a)>>(a);  // OK
  f<decltype(b), conditional_ref<decltype(b)>>(b);  // OK

  return 0;
}
```

In this, `f<decltype(a)>` deduces to `f<A, A>` instead of the expected `f<A, A const&>`.
I have tried in clang-10, gcc-9, and Visual Studio 2019; all of these give the same result, so I think I'm doing something wrong.
Example output from clang-10:

```
$ clang-10 test.cpp
test.cpp:9:3: error: static_assert failed due to requirement 'std::is_same<A, const A &>::value' "uh-oh!"
  static_assert(std::is_same<Ty2_, conditional_ref<Ty_>>::value, "uh-oh!");
  ^             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
test.cpp:19:3: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'f<A, A>' requested here
  f<decltype(a)>(a);                                // uh-oh!
  ^
1 error generated.
```

**Why is the template deduction not what I expect here?**

**How do I rewrite `f()` so that it accepts a `Ty_` when passed a fundamental type, and a `Ty_ const&` otherwise?** Preferably while only having to pass the type of the argument once, like `f<decltype(a)>(a)`.

Comment: Try `decltype((a))`.  See [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype) for examples and explanation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Significance of parentheses in decltype((c))?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14115744/significance-of-parentheses-in-decltypec)

Comment: Even if I try `f<A>(a);`, filling in the type directly it still deduces to `f<A, A>` instead of `f<A, A const&>`. I don't think the issue is with the `decltype`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Ty2_` is deducible, so default is not used at all. you might use directly:

```
template <typename Ty_>
void f(conditional_ref<Ty_> arg1) {
  static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(arg1), conditional_ref<Ty_>>::value, "uh-oh!");
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Ydhb8d)

Answer (score 0):

Type of `Ty2_` is deduced by provided argument of function call. You can disable this deduction by

```
void f(std::type_identity_t<Ty2_> arg1)
```

then default template parameter type will be used.